# Datatables no value for date should return "No date", laravel 5

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a datatable which takes a date, in my mysql no date is supplied so I would like "No date" to appear in the table instead of 01-01-1970. I have read around and found the following code to try and fix my column 0 with date in.
My JQuery looks like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#new_table').DataTable({
 "aoColumns":[
              null,
                {
                'mRender': function(data, type, full){
                    if (full[0] != ''){
                     // display date
                     return full[0];
                        }else{
                        return "No Date";
                        }    
                       }
                  }    
               ]
         });
    } );
        </script>
```

Table is as:

```
 <table id="new_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover responsive resourceTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Date Received</th>
                               </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                       @foreach($inventory_items as $item)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{date('d-M-Y', strtotime($item->date_received))}}</td>
                            </tr>
                       @endforeach
            </tbody>
   </table>
```

I can't seem to work out why it wont return the string as described in the Jquery, any help would be awesome. Thanks MRF

Comment: What is in the cell when you view the source?

Comment: Further: it seems as though you're passing a null - or in some other way borked - value to `strtotime`... what I'd suggest is not using PHPs `date` function but to render the value without PHP and then getting a column render function with, for instance, moment.js to check the value - if it's not a valid date then return "No date"; if it is render as you'd like.

Comment: In the cell is 01-01-1970. I am using laravel 5. I'll see if I can work around strtotime

Comment: Try: `(is_null($item->date_received)) ? "No date" : date('d-M-Y', strtotime($item->date_received))`

Comment: Nope still gives me the 01-Jan-1970

Comment: I can work around it by entering it all as text, but would liked to have had the format of the time rather than the text in the DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94690/discussion-between-annoyingmouse-and-mrf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion:

If this is available:

```
function IsNullOrEmptyString($question){
    return (!isset($question) || trim($question)==='');
}
```

You could use this:

```
{{(IsNullOrEmptyString($item->date_received)) ? "No date" : date('d-M-Y', strtotime($item->date_received))}}
```